# Запуск сторонних приложений из программы

Tags: c++, linux, pipes

У меня есть класс `PipeLine` для запуска сторонних программ: https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/crossplatform/console.cpp#L590.

Для запуска сторонней программы нужно вызвать `Run()`, передав в нее имя программы. https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/crossplatform/console.cpp#L694

Функция `Run()` создает 4 пайпа, далее с помощью вызова `fork()` создает еще один процесс, в котором через `system()` запускает указанную программу. А так же перенаправляет stdin и компанию в родительский процесс.

Этот код отлично работает, но, замечены периодические "зависания" на `select()`, https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/crossplatform/console.cpp#L814.

Я запускаю /usr/bin/php-cgi, минимум пару раз в минуту. Примерно раз в пол часа один из потоков виснет на `select()`. php-cgi в списке процессов нет. Похоже, что дочерний поток завершается, не закрыв пайпы, но я не вижу, как такая ситуация может возникнуть.

Подскажите, где может быть ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте защитить процесс запуска внешней задачи семафором от момента создания пар сокетов (pipes) до закрытия сокетов, дуплицирующихся для потомка. Есть ощущение, что при одновременном запуске нескольких внешних процессов возможна путаница в том, какие из сокетов родительского процесса им наследовать. В результате может потеряться сигнал о закрытии пайпа со стороны потомка.